# Form/posture/technique for ruck running

Tags: running

I am about to start with ruck running (running with a loaded backpack).

All I know about it is to build up the weight very gradually.

However, I would like to understand the proper form/posture for running with a loaded backpack. I assume shorter steps than usual. What else? Off the top of my head, I can only think of two added factors. Please add anything else you know from experience.

1. Should I bend forward a little more? Or instead make an effort to stay upright?
2. Should my strike (fore/mid/rear-foot) be modified in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this for military practice purpose so you can get prepared for military, or just for your own health?
As a runner you never want to lean forward because that would be harsh on your back, especially if you have a backpack weight always want your chest up and look straight and run with opposite arm to knee. Loosen up your arms and self, make sure you stretch your back and also have some sort of back workout so you don't hurt your back, or your back won't be as weak as you gradually ump the weight. Focus on your strides and make an effort to keep it equally the same every stride.